# How not to show the password when changing the user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a custom UserAdmin with custom fileds. When i add new user it is ok. But when i want to change user info i see his hashed password. How not to show the password?
[image]

It's my overriding User admin.

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    middle_name = forms.CharField(label='Отчество', empty_value='1 ', required=False)

    class Meta:
        labels = {
            'last_name': 'Фамилия',
            'first_name': 'Имя',
            'password': 'Пароль',
        }


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserAdminForm
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'groups']
    list_display = ['username', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'url_get_money_from_user']

    def url_get_money_from_user(self, obj):
        return format_html('<a href="/admin/fbp_common/person/{}/change/">{}</a>', obj.person.id, 'Списать средства')

    url_get_money_from_user.allow_tags = True
    url_get_money_from_user.short_description = 'Ссылка для списания денежных средств'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.is_staff = True
        obj.set_password(form.data['password'])
        obj.save()
```

Comment: try to inherit your `UserAdmin` from `from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin` instead of `ModelAdmin` and also check [readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I should to use `PasswordInput` and put it to `widgets` in `class Meta`

```
from django.forms import PasswordInput

class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    middle_name = forms.CharField(label='Отчество', empty_value='1 ', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'groups']
        labels = {
            'last_name': 'Фамилия',
            'first_name': 'Имя',
            'password': 'Пароль',
        }
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput(),
        }
```

And i getting empty input field for password.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want to override [get_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) form method to dynamically change fields depending on create/change action in admin:

```
def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj:
       # record already exists - lets hide the password
       return ('username', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'groups')
    return super().get_fields(request, obj)
```